# Avoid warning "a set method for non-dependent property should not access ..."

Tags: matlab, oop, warnings

I have a class which has some properties and 2 are related, in the example called `param1, param2`. They are independent, just constrained. `param2` must be as large or larger than `param1` and must always exist if `param1` does. Code in question is something like:

```
    function set.param1(obj, input)
        disp('setting param1')
        obj.param1 = input;
        if (isempty(obj.param2) || obj.param2 < obj.param1) % Warning on param2
           obj.param2 = obj.param1; % Warning on param2
        end
    end
```

Similar code for the `set.param2`.
Code works fine and I cannot see any better way to do it. The problem - it produces warning "a set method..." like mentioned in title. I suppressed them for the lack of better solution. 
Is there a better way to achieve this functionality and without warnings? Obviously not a hacky "solution" like a hidden function `SetParam2`:

```
function SetParam2(obj, input)
   obj.param2 = input;
end
```

which confuses editor just enough it doesn't complain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use two layers of properties

- one layer which is exposed and `Dependent`
- one layer which is private and actually stores the values

The similar technique is used here in the documentation: [Avoid Property Initialization Order Dependency](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/avoiding-property-initialization-order-dependency.html).

```
classdef TestClass < handle  
    properties (Access = private)
        privateParam1;
        privateParam2;
    end

    properties (Dependent)
         param1;
         param2;
    end

    methods
        function p1 = get.param1(obj)
            p1 = obj.privateParam1;
        end

        function p2 = get.param2(obj)
            p2 = obj.privateParam2;
        end

        function set.param1(obj, input)
            obj.privateParam1 = input;
            if (isempty(obj.privateParam2) || obj.privateParam2 < obj.privateParam1)
                obj.privateParam2 = obj.param1; 
            end
        end

         function set.param2(obj, input)
            if (~isempty(obj.privateParam1) && obj.privateParam1 > input)
                obj.privateParam2 = obj.privateParam1;
            else
                obj.privateParam2 = input;
            end
         end
    end
end
```

The trick here: `privateParam1` and `privateParam2` stores the two values. The get and set only implemented for the exposed properties `param1` and `param2`: the `get` returns simply the inner property and in the `set` both of them can be used without the analyzer warning as they are marked as `Dependent`.